Can't launch The First Descendant on Steam (seems driver related?)
Quick overview: Game was running fine on 24.04, then I upgraded to 24.10, it stopped working.
I updated the Nvidia driver from 530 to 550 - it worked for a bit, then after an update to the game, no dice again. Now it's stuck in not running past the Easy Anti-cheat screen.
I've tried the game on both the Flatpak and Snap installs of Steam and it's the same thing.
I'm now on the 560 driver and still nothing.
Perhaps someone knows of something?
My hardware:

MSI Raider GE76 11UE
64GB RAM 6GB
Nvidia Geforce RTX 3060


Have you checked protondb to see if there's any tweaks you need to use for that game? https://www.protondb.com/app/2074920?device=any

I never needed to before, but checking now. Most folks seem to report no issues (just as was the case for me before).

As Popey suggested, I went poking around on Proton DB, and finally found a fix:
DXVK_FILTER_DEVICE_NAME="NVIDIA GeForce RTX 4060" %command%

Just placed 4060 with 3060 and... it worked!
DXVK_FILTER_DEVICE_NAME="NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3060" %command%

